# Automatic first line in vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to make vim write something on the first line (or on few first lines) automatically everytime when I create file with a specific extension?

For example (and this is only an example) if I create .txt file I would like vim to write "Hello" on the first line.

Is it possible? If it is, how?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can achieve this with [autocommands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html). The general structure of an autocommand is

```
au event filetype command
```

In your specific case, you want

```
au BufNewFile *.txt normal iHello
```

Explanation:

```
au            "Define a new autocommand
BufNewFile    "When you create a new file
*.txt         "With the extension '.txt'
normal iHello "Execute the command 'normal iHello', which is like typing 'iHello' manually
```

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#skeleton) give an idea of how to do this in `:h skeleton`. Essentially, you just need a `BufNewFile` autocommand in your `.vimrc`.

The docs assume you'll be reading your initial content from a file. So, for your example, assuming `skeleton.txt` contains the text "Hello":

`autocmd BufNewFile *.txt 0r ~/vim/skeleton.txt`

Alternatively, if your first line is relatively simple, you can always hardcode it by just entering insert mode and adding the text you need.

`au BufNewFile *.txt normal iHello`

[This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8442) from vi.stackexchange provides a couple examples that call functions and are a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to bash files, I have this on my ~/.vimrc

```
augroup sh
  au BufNewFile *.sh 0r ~/.vim/skel/template.sh
 "au BufWritePost *.sh,*.pl,*.py,*.cgi :silent !chmod a+x <afile>
augroup end
```

If I create a new file "BufNewFile" vim opens at the line zero "0" by reading "r" the content of the file template.sh, on that file I can put wherever I want.

If I uncoment the seccond line removing the " at beginning I have also a change on file permission automatically